# Get Progress To Angular 4 from Async C# Method

Tags: c#, angular, asynchronous

it tries to upload excel file from angular to the c# async method and read it 
and return the progress to angular until it finishes but it's not working
but it keeps stop in first return

any way to fix it and return my pertc to angular HTTP post

my c# code is

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(IFormFile files)
    {

        string hresult = "done";

        string message = "uploaded Successfully";

        try
        {
            Stream stream = files.OpenReadStream();

            var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            var fileContent = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)files.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContent);

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
                bool bHeaderRow = true;
                int tempCount = 0;
                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
                    {
                        if (bHeaderRow)
                        {
                            sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                        }

                        var pertc = tempCount * 100 / rowCount;
                        tempCount++;
                        var progresult = new ObjectResult(pertc)
                        {
                            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
                        };
                        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", "Working");
                        return progresult;


                    }
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            hresult = ex.Message;


        }

        var result = new ObjectResult(message)
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", hresult);
        return result;


    }
```

and I call it from angular like this

```
  const fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;

    if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('files', fileBrowser.files[0]);





        this.http.post('/api/Main/UploadFiles', formData)
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                 console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
                console.log("Error occured");
            }
            );
```

any way to get the percentage from async c# method to get it in angular

Comment: Not from a POST. Take a look at [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) for details about how to send notifications back to your webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with HTTP calls, as they allow only one response per request and the server does not know about any clients.

If you want your angular app to actively receive messages from a server than you have to use `WebSockets` on both the front-end and your back-end. There are several tutorials showing angular services which provide simple solutions, unfortunally can't say much about C# site.

Else you could poll (HTTP GET) the current status of process in an interval, which is of cause not perfecly accurate but probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OkObjectResult Ok` method in this way `return Ok(progresult);`

For example:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(IFormFile files)
    {

        string hresult = "done";

        string message = "uploaded Successfully";

        try
        {
            Stream stream = files.OpenReadStream();

            var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            var fileContent = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)files.Length);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContent);

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                int ColCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
                bool bHeaderRow = true;
                int tempCount = 0;
                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= ColCount; col++)
                    {
                        if (bHeaderRow)
                        {
                            sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.Append(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString() + "\t");
                        }

                        var pertc = tempCount * 100 / rowCount;
                        tempCount++;
                        var progresult = new ObjectResult(pertc)
                        {
                            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
                        };
                        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", "Working");
                        return Ok(progresult);


                    }
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            hresult = ex.Message;


        }

        var result = new ObjectResult(message)
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", hresult);
        return Ok(result);


    }
```

On Angular .ts file:

```
this.http.post('/api/Main/UploadFiles', formData)
            .map((res: Response) =>
            {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(error =>
            {
                console.log("Error occured");
            });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think he wants the result of the method (which in his code will always return 0 or 'uploaded Successfully')